# Delete/reset a displayed picture from vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to remove image src,
here is my template

```
<div class="file-upload-section">
  <label id="preview" for="file-upload">
      <img v-if="url" :src="url" />
  </label>
  <div class="file-upload">
    <label class="file-upload-button" for="file-upload">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-upload" @change="onFileChange"/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="url">
    <button @click="removeImage()">Remove image</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my script

```
data: function () {
    return {
      url: null,
      file: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange (e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
      this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
    },
    removeImage: function () {
      this.url = null
    }
  }
}
```

this is all i did, am i doing anything wrong or there is another way to delete a picture from a img

Comment: The above way is good. Are you having any error when using the above code?

Comment: The problem could be re render checkout this post https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: `reemoveImage` != `removeImage`

Comment: this what i see on console inspector"removeImage" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.  @YashMaheshwari

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit:

On testing your code, I noticed the file preview does reset (the url variable), however the value of the input, did not. I assume that's what you mean, thus:

You can use a ref on the file input, and reset it as well.

Add a ref to your input:
`<input type="file" id="file-upload" ref="file" @change="onFileChange"/>`

Also, update your removeImage method accordingly:

```
removeImage: function () {
      this.url = ""
      this.$refs.file.value = ""
    }
```

[Pen here](https://codepen.io/jvhellemondt/pen/NWbJNMv)

Comment: Adding `()` will not call the function, its just binding it. see the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html). I don't understand why this answer is accepeted even though its a blunder.

Comment: @jens removing or adding (), won't affect executions, see [event docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Your code is working**; I tried it in my environment. It works perfectly. The issue could be re-rendering. I removed the "file" variable, as this seems no use based on your code, and I created scoped variable inside **onFileChange function**.

For a re-rendering issue to fix, add the **key** in your "img" tag and give it a unique value which will change on the "add" and "remove" image. In the below case, I use "URL" as a key.

```
<img :key="url" v-if="url" :src="url" />
```

Here is the code, give it a try:

```
<template>
  <div class="file-upload-section">
    <label id="preview" for="file-upload">
        <img :key="url" v-if="url" :src="url" />
    </label>
    <div class="file-upload">
      <label class="file-upload-button" for="file-upload">Upload Image</label>
      <input type="file" id="file-upload" @change="onFileChange"/>
    </div>
    <div v-if="url">
      <button @click="removeImage()">Remove image</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        url: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onFileChange (e) {
        let file = e.target.files[0]
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      },
      removeImage: function () {
        this.url = null
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: why do you use a mixed declaration? You can write `data() {` instead of `data: function ()` and `removeImage()` instead of `removeImage: function ()` - If you give an answer please be as much as clean as possible

Comment: @wittgenstein I wrote the code that way because of the questioner; his code was like that, so as not to confuse him with another form of functions code; he may think that he made a mistake while writing those functions and that the problem was.

Answer (score -3):

In Vuejs in order to bind an event you should use v-on:click or in short way :click:

```
<button :click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: The event short bind is with "@" and not with ":", as this ":" we use to bind variables.